# Factoranalysis in Multilevel Model in R

Tags: factor-analysis, multilevel-analysis

Unfortunately, I can't find literature on how to conduct factor analyses in a multilevel design (with individuals, countries and time as hierarchical levels) in R.
The factors are suggested to be on the individual level.

Could anyone help?